# Como retornar dados de um arquivo json de forma crescente, diferente da raíz dos objetos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

eu quero retornar dados de um arquivo json, porém eu quero que eles sejam imprimidos na página de baixo para cima, ou seja, os dados mais recentes, que por padrão da raíz são escritos de cima para baixo no json, apareçam sempre no topo da página, como um feed de notícias. Não colocarei o código aqui pois creio que é uma questão mais de lógica de algoritmo e pode ser exemplificada com um array ou objetos JavaScript/Jquery.

Comment: Luan, a lógica é só iterar no seu JSON de trás pra frente. Se você precisar de mais detalhes seria interessante adicionar mais informações, como a estrutura do JSON que você recebe, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se o que você quer é ordenar um array (no seu caso o json) pela ordem inversa, basta usar o metodo **reverse** do objeto **Array**.

```js
const arr = [
  {name: 'jose', idade: 32},
  {name: 'ana', idade: 36},
  {name: 'fran', idade: 34}
];

arr.reverse();

arr.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```